# Why does this where filter not work in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, github-pages

I have a github page, whose `_include` directory has a file courses.html:

```
{% assign id = include.lessonID | split: '.' %}
{% assign courseID = id | first %}
{% assign node = site.data.courses | where: "id","1" %}

{% assign node = node[1] %}

{%- if node.id == empty -%}
  <h1> EMPTY NODE Warning</h1>
{%- else -%}
  <h2> DATA Found! </h2>
  ID: {{ node.id }}
{%- endif -%}

<p>CourseID: {{node.id}}</p>
<p>Name: {{ node.name }}</p>
<p>Link: {{ node.permalink }}</p>

{%- for node in site.data.courses -%}
  {%- if node.id == 1 -%}
    <p>{{ node.name }}</p>
    <p>{{ node.permalink }}</p>
  {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
```

It is being used by a file in `_layout` called courses.html:

```
{% include courses.html post=page.lessonInfo.lessonID post=page %}
```

Finally, there's file `lister.md` that has the following contents:

```
---
layout: courses
title:  'Test'
lessonInfo:
  lessonID : 1.1
  modName: 'Installing RHEL Server'
  chapterName: 'Using Essential Tools'
---

# There should be some course list around here!
```

The output is as follows:

> DATA Found!
>   ID:
>   CourseID:
>   Name:
>   Link:
>   RHCSA
>   /rhcsa

So, apparently the `node` variable isn't empty, but I can't access any of the properties when I'm selecting the right element of the array using `where` clause.

However, this works when using the second part using `if` statement in `for` loop. How do I fix the where clause?!

---

### Edit

The suggestions by @JJJ did solve my problem, but I have a related problem now. I can't replace the constant `1` in the expression `where: "id","1"` with a variable! I tried the normal where clause (both with and without quotes) which didn't work. So, I tried a where expression, which also doesn't work:

```
{% assign node = site.data.courses | where: "id",courseID %}
```

> Doesn't work!

```
{% assign node = site.data.courses | where_exp: "selNode","selNode.id == courseID" %}
```

> Neither does this.

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post different problems in separate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, like in most programming languages, arrays are zero-indexed. `node[1]` contains the second node, not the first one. You probably meant `{% assign node = node[0] %}` instead.

Secondly, `if node.id == empty` isn't how you check if a value exists. Just do `unless node` or `node.size == 0`.

Comment: How is a variable evaluated to be _empty_ then? In which circumstances?

Comment: please check out my edit to the question (at the bottom). I tried your solution, but can't seem to adapt it to fit my problem!

Comment: That is a completely different problem. Please post it as a separate question.